# Graph Database Data Model of One Type of Object

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

Say I'm a mechanic who's worked on many different cars and would like to keep a  database of the cars I've worked on. These cars have different manufacturers, models, and some customers have modified versions of these cars with different parts so it's not guaranteed the same model gives you the same car. In addition, I would like to see all these different cars and their similarities/differences easily. Basically the database needs to both represent the logical similarities/differences between all cars that I encounter while still giving me the ability to push/pull each instance of a car I've encountered.

1. Is this more set up for a relational or graph database?
2. If a graph database, how would you go about designing it? Each of the relationship labels would just be a 'has_a' or 'is_a_type_of'. Would you have the logical structure amongst all the cars and for each individual car have them point to the leaf nodes? Or would you have each relationship represent each specific car and have those relationships span the logical tree structure of the cars?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so a "graphy" way to go about this would be to create a node type for each kind of domain object.  You have a `Car` identified by a `VIN`, it can be linked to a `Make`, `Model`, and `Year`.   You also have `Mechanic` nodes that `[:work_on]` various `Car` nodes.  Don't store make/model/year with the Car, but rather link via relationships, e.g.:

```
CREATE (c:Car { VIN: "ABC"})-[:make]->(m:Make {label:"Toyota"});
```

...and so on.

> Each of the relationship labels would just be a 'has_a' or
>   'is_a_type_of'.

Probably no, I'd create different relationship types unique to pairings of node types.  So Mechanic -> Car would be `:works_on`, Car -> Model would be `[:model]` and so on.  I don't recommend using the same relationship type like `has_a` everywhere, because from a modeling perspective it's harder to sort out the valid domain and ranges of those relationships (e.g. you'll end up in a situation where `has_a` can go from just about anything to just about anything, and picking out which `has_a` relationships you want will be hard).

> Or would you have each relationship represent each specific car and
>   have those relationships span the logical tree structure of the cars?

Each car is its own node, identified by something like a VIN, not by a make/model/year.   (Splitting out make/model/year later will allow you to very easily query for all Volvos, etc).

Your last question (and the toughest one):

> Is this more set up for a relational or graph database?

This is an opinionated question (it attracts opinionated answers), let me put it to you this way:  any data under the sun can be done both relationally and via graphs.  So I could answer *both* yes relational, and yes graph.   Your data and your domain doesn't select whether you should do RDBMS or Graph.  Your queries and access patterns select RDBMS vs. graph.   If you know how you need to use your data, which queries you'll run, and what you're trying to do, then with that information in hand, you can do your own analysis and determine which one is better.  Both have strengths and weaknesses and many points of tradeoff.  Without knowing how you'll access the data, it's impossible to answer this question in a really fair way.